# Variable rule for one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can I have a cell display a one of 3 different predetermined figures based on the contents of 3 other cells? I need it to understand that depending on how many of a certain thing is performed in one day that an expected target of something else should be added to a total. For example, if an employee takes over 10 calls it is assumed that they are on the phone all day and should therefore be able to respond to a KPI of 50 emails. If they take less than 10 calls it is assumed they are on other functions and would not be expected to respond to 50 emails. I want the spreadsheet to calculate their KPI over a month based on their functions each day.

The cell that contains the formula is D62. I want D62 to display 200 if the number in T3 is greater than 10 and 0 if it is less than 10. However, the other variable is that if the number in T3 is less than 10 but the number in BP3 is greater than 10 I need D62 to display 50.

=IF(T3>10,200,0,IF(BP3>10,50,0)) This is where I got to

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, Super User is not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Hint: ``IF()``.

Comment: So if an employee takes 11 calls, they're on the phone all day.  If they're on the phone all day, how do they have time to respond to 50 emails?  If they take 9 calls instead of 11, they're on the phone 9/11 as much, but you assume they're too busy doing other things to respond to emails?  If I was in that situation, I would simply make sure I don't take more than 9 calls.  Then I would obviously be too busy to respond to emails.

Comment: The 10 is just a parameter which will occasionally have exceptions, but in most scenarios if they take more than 10 calls they would actually be taking 60+ calls and vice versa if they take less than 10 calls they would most likely take 0/1 calls as they would be too busy doing emails to take calls. I need the formula to cover the largest amount of variables, and with the numbers I have 10 is the best point to go above and below to make sure the calculation is right on the majority of days.

Comment: Also, the figure being displayed in the cell (0, 50 or 200) is their KPI for a completely separate task, something which only takes a few seconds to look at and complete each one. That number will ultimately display on a personalised dashboard I have created for each employee so that they are able to track their progress each month against their KPI. This is why I need it to know what task they have been doing as the KPI in question varies depending on the task and is obviously 0 if they are on leave.

Comment: I have been trying it now with AND and OR functions, like so: =IF(AND(OR(T3>10,200,0),BP3>10,50))  but I am still no closer to resolving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close:

```
=IF(T3>10, 200, IF(BP3>10, 50, 0))
```

Comment: That's worked! Thank you so much for your help!